# Android Jetpack navigation deeplinks not generating well on AndroidManifest

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-jetpack, deeplink, android-jetpack-navigation

### The problem

I'm having trouble with deeplinks in Android navigation XML

```
<fragment
        ...
        <deepLink app:uri="app://contact" />
</fragment>
```

Then Jetpack library generates this code in the Merged *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<intent-filter
    ...
    <data android:scheme="app"/>
    <data android:host="contact"/>
    <data android:path="/"/>
```

This last line generates that my deep link is not recognized when I execute it manually from the command line:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "app://contact"

or

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "app://contact/"
```

The problem is partially solved adding '/' at the first bunch of code

```
     <deepLink app:uri="app://contact/" />
```

This also generates the same code in the AndroidManifest.xml 
After doing it, the following deep link works: *"app://contact/"*

### Question:

is there a way to make it work using just *"app://contact"* ?

Comment: same problem and same workaround :/